Will gradient boosting monotonically decrease error?
I’m still trying to wrap my head around gradient boosting for regression, specifically xgboost, and I’m trying to understand if it’s guaranteed that each step is guaranteed to produce smaller residuals in the subsequent iteration. If we are guaranteed to decrease our loss function monotonically, is it on a per-sample level (i.e the pseudo-residual of sample i is guaranteed to decrease for all i after every iteration) or is it the sum of the squared errors over all i is guaranteed to decrease?
My thought is that since the loss function is the sum of all squared errors, we are minimizing that, but it is not guaranteed that each sample residual will go down each iteration. And I’m trying to think of a case where you could add a new tree and it actually increase the sum of error (like if your regression tree is very poor). I’m stuck if there could be a case where the new tree’s predictions of pseudo-residuals are so poor that they actually increase error.

By construction each new tree works on the residuals of the preceding trees to reduce the loss function. That's always on average (or sum) across the records to which the new tree is fit. So, even if the average loss improves, the loss for individual records could increase. Normally, you'd expect at least a tiny improvement in the average loss on the training data (it might of course not be by much, especially with very low learning rates it is common that you sometimes don't see much happening up to the number of decimal places being displayed).
Scenarios where the average loss does not improve could include:

You use sub-sampling of records for each tree (one quite good way of regularizing/reducing overfitting). What reduces average loss on the records you picked to construct the next tree does not on average reduce loss on all records. In such a case loss could get worse.
Your fit is close to minimizing the loss function on the training data and within the hyperparameters you've set (i.e. in terms of how many records there must be on each side of a split, how much a split must help etc.) there's no possible split that would reduce average loss. If you set hyperparameters that force a split anyway, you might even get increased loss.

Of course, an improvement in the average loss on the training data is at some point no longer what you want. That's when improving further becomes overfitting and regularization parameters that prevent that (see example above) are a good thing. That's why something like cross-validation (or whatever is appropriate for the particular circumstances) is so important to monitor prediction performance on data not being used to train the model.
